# Ubuntu 22.04 bluetooth not finding devices (specifically a bluetooth speaker)

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, hp, soundcard, bluetooth-speaker

I have a Soundcore Select 2 and my Ubuntu 22.04 isn’t able to pair with it. The hardware is a HP Prodesk 600 G4DM.

If on startup, on the black screen before the Ubuntu logo shows up, I see some error message briefly about hc10 unable to start, failure to start, or something like that, then when I go to Settings > Bluetooth > Enable the "Devices" will have a little spinning circle that will spin forever with no devices showing even though I have put the Soundcore Select 2 into pairing mode and physically placed it right next to the computer.

If there is no error message during start up, I can see the Soundcore Select 2 appear under "Devices" with the words "Not set up".
I tried clicking on the Soundcore Select 2 option hoping to set up but clicking it just makes it disappear from the list briefly before reappearing again.

[An image of what the bluetooth settings looks like - it shows the bluetooth speaker but clicking it makes it disappear, the Devices wheel spins, then the speaker reappears still saying "Not set up"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppdaq.png)

Initially, I thought it was the audio/sound card that is not working but when I tried `alsamixer`, it is able to display the sound card as "HDA Intel PCH" and the sound chip as "Conexant CX20632", which I think is correct.

I've tried other sources of audio like plugging headphones into TRS jacks and audio output works fine.

`sudo service bluetooth status` output:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-05-06 11:36:24 EDT; 36min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 707 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18838)
     Memory: 2.1M
        CPU: 161ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─707 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 06 11:36:24 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
May 06 11:36:24 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
May 06 11:36:25 prodesk bluetoothd[707]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
```

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Active Management Technology - SOL (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

`lspci -k -s 02:00.0` output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`dmesg | grep -i blue` output:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.952279] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.952299] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.952300] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.952303] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.952305] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.952308] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.195301] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[    5.217099] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.217101] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.217105] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.610444] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.610449] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.610453] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  852.329367] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000762fe64b failed to resubmit (2)
[  861.718769] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
```

`systemctl | grep -i blue` output:

```
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d14-1\x2d14:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device        loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                               loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0
  bluetooth.service                                                                         loaded active     running   Bluetooth service
  bluetooth.target                                                                          loaded active     active    Bluetooth Support
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`rfkill list all` output:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

`rfkill unblock bluetooth`
`rfkill list all` output:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Problem persists

If any1 has suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like the OS is searching are the Select 2  listening?

Comment: @David Yeah, looks like restarting helped it find the listing but it doesn't connect/isn't able to set up.